# Async loading files with Angular into an object array and keeping their order

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loading, sequential

I'm not loading scripts, I'm reading XML files into an array of objects.
My first [dumb] attempt was something like:

```
for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    var filePath = "xml/chapter_"+i+".xml";
    $http.get( filePath ).success(function (data) {
        $scope.chaptersData.push (data._chapter); 
    });
}
```

I quickly figured out this was no good, because the array will be filled in the order the files *finished* loading, not when they started (a race condition) and the smaller ones will finish first. I can't use the value of 'i' because of course it gets to 'n' long before any of the loading finishes.

After that I thought `success(function (data, i) {` would work, but it didn't. I'm out of simple ideas, and before I come up with some kind of Rube Goldberg kludge I thought I would ask the wisdom of the Internets if there is a 'right' way to do this.

Comment: The last time I did something like this, it was also a Rube Goldberg kludge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `i` into a function which performs the request.

```
for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    getFile(i);
}

function getFile(index){
    var filePath = "xml/chapter_" + index + ".xml";
    $http.get( filePath ).success(function (data) {
        $scope.chaptersData[index] = data._chapter; 
    });
}
```

Within the `getFile` function, the value of the parameter `index` will not change as `i` changes in the outer function. So it will still be at its initial value when the success function executes and can be used for populating the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just get data as an object like

```
{
  order: [] // just your chapter id or whatever identifier value in desired order
  data: // whatever you're getting now 
}
```

In your .success (which is btw depreciated and you should use .then() instead) just do

```
orderedChapters = [];

for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; i++) {
    if (order[i] == data[j].id) {
      orderedChapters.push(data[j]);
    }
  }
}
```